# Setting Spark master url automatically when running locally

Tags: apache-spark

I have a Spark application that can be run both in local mode or on a real cluster. Currently we pass a CLI argument --local, so that if it's set, we initialize the master URL:

```
sparkBuilder = sparkBuilder.master("local[*]")
```

Is it possible to figure out that we're running in a standalone mode, so that we can automatically decide when we need to initialize the local master?

Comment: why you dont pass it in spark-submit ?

Comment: That's what we do now. The question is whether there's an option to figure it out without passing explicitly.